# JavaScript - Wired behavior of Array_Push()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a weird behavior of Array_Push(). I am adding array to predefined array. Problem is that for some reason length of array increase for two when I am pushing array to predefined array.

Here is code:

example array:

```
Object {id: 2, firstName: "First name", lastName: "Last name", phones: Array[0], emails: Array[0]…}$$hashKey: "00A"address: "Street 3"city: "Washington "emails: Array[0]firstName: "First name"id: 2lastName: "Last name"notes: "No notes"phones: Array[0]__proto__: Object
```

JavaScript:

```
var contacts = [
        {
            id: 0,
            firstName: 'John',
            lastName: 'Doe',
            phones: [{'phone1': '222222222'}],
            emails: [{'email1': 'example@mail.com'}],
            address: 'Some Streetz 2.',
            city: 'Las Vegas',
            notes: 'Napomena',
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            firstName: 'Mike',
            lastName: 'Smith',
            phones: [{'phone1':'111111'}],
            emails: [{'email1': 'example@mail.com'}],           
            address: '459 5th Av.',
            city: 'New York',
            notes: 'Napomena',
        }
    ];
```

adding array to contacts array

```
this.addContact = function (contact) {

        alert (contacts.length);//output is 2
        contact.id = contacts.length ++;//getting ID od new array
        console.log(contact);//
        contacts.push(contact);
                        alert ("++"+contacts.length);//output is 4

                console.log(contacts);

    };
```

Comment: don't use the unary `++` on the length property!

Comment: As a guess, I would say you read some tutorial that included incrementing the length counter whenever you add an element, however the internal implementation of JavaScript Arrays takes care of this for us. No need to go length++, the array will automatically update the length property when you manipulate the array eg using push().

Comment: you are correct @DanielA.White . Amadan suggested that in comment so I fixed that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contacts.length++` increases the length of the array, essentially being equivalent to `contacts.push(undefined)`. Then you add another element.

`contact.id = contacts.length` is the correct choice. And if you needed to have "one larger than length" (which you don't), `contact.id = contacts.length + 1` would be the correct way to write it.